# LXDM and Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: unity, lubuntu, 15.04, lightdm, lxdm

Currently, the lightdm is burning up too much CPU resource on my computer and from the searches I've done, it's a heavy display manager. Example, just having wunderlist web page open in firefox, the lightdm shoots up to 50cpu alone on Unity. But on Lubuntu desktop environment, it's berable like 14-20cpu.

My computer really isn't that ancient as I don't really have display issues with Windows 8.1. I'm currently running Lubuntu D.E but I really like to use Unity.

Is it possible to run lxdm display manager on Unity? I only installed lxdm which was 800kb but it failed to start. Gave me issues like these,

```
Failed to start lxdm.service
```

running {systemctl status lxdm.service}

```
Loaded: Error
Active: Inactive
```

I installed {ldxm} with the following command

```
sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends install lxdm
```

Ubuntu 15.04

```
3.19.0-21-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Sun Jun 14 18:31:11 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**Update**

I have done dpkg reconfigure method of selecting lxdm, it boots and the entire UI is in crash like phase. Like there are no Windows border. **I have given up now and going to stick with lightdm until I feel I need to leave entire distro and move on to Linuxmint mate or Linux Lite**

Answer (score 0):

For each xserver you can only run one display manager at a time. When installing a new display manager on the command line you usually get a dialog asking which one you want by defualt. To run this again you can try running sudo dpkg-reconfigure lxdm and should get a dialog and select lxdm instead of lightdm as the display manager. Although unity is a heavier desktop environment that could use resources in lightdm.

Comment: Enabling lxdm by service lightdm stop service lxdm start. But it won't start  Then I ran dpkg configure and put lxdm as default. The login occurs like in xfce but a few miles later the things bugs to splash screen.  Doing alt cntrl f1 showed the fullscreen terminal for a split second before reverting back to splash screen. I had to reboot and get back to login screen and revert back lightdm from there.